# How to remove Article schema from joomla?

Tags: php, joomla

I dont have any idea about joomla.
I want to remove itemtype="http://schema.org/Article" from one article.
As suggested in this link https://www.tassos.gr/joomla-extensions/google-structured-data-markup/docs/how-to-remove-the-default-joomla-microdata 
I removed it from /components/com_content/views/article/tmpl/default.php page
but still it's there only.
please help me, if anyone have idea about it.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check to see if your template has a template override, so like /template/TEMPLATE_NAME/html/com_content/article/default.php.  If so, do the same thing there.